# Can I enter Mexico with a United States C-1 visa without transiting through the US?

Tags: visas, usa, transit-visas, mexico, uzbek-citizens

I really need help as I recently faced a dilemma related to Mexican visa. I am a Uzbekistan passport holder and, in the near future, I'm going to visit Mexico for tourism.

Am I allowed to enter Mexico with C1 visa for transit through the United States? It would not be *via* the USA but *via other countries.*

Getting a Mexico visa is not easy, as there is no Mexican Consulate in Uzbekistan. To get a visa for Mexico, I would have to go to Iran, first get an Iranian visa, then stay in Iran for several weeks. It is very time and money consuming, so the most suitable solution for me in this situation is the C1 visa.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111077/does-a-c1-us-transit-visa-allow-entry-and-travel-tourist-in-mexico

Answer (score 8):

[According to the Mexican consul in San Francisco](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico), it looks like you should be able to use your US visa for tourism entry to Mexico as long as it's still valid:

> With the purpose of facilitating and promoting travel to Mexico,
>   effective May 2016 all those foreign nationals, regardless of their
>   nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT
>   required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a valid (non-expired)
>   Visa or Permanent Residence of any of this countries: United States of
>   America, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or Schengen area (European
>   Union).

You may wish to call the nearest Mexican consulate to you to double-check this advice since it is from 2016 and also since your US visa is only valid for transit. I doubt the fact that you are not using it for transit *on this visit* would be relevant but perhaps you should ask about that too. I would also print the page from the consulate to take with you in case of any confusion.